# Angular not defined in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I often use a variation of `angular.element($0).scope()` as a way of debugging angular issues.

However since moving to a new computer Developer tools always returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

Angular itself is running fine and is not minified (in dev environment) and I've 'inspected' an element which is in the correct scope.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to debug Angular2

Comment: This is angular 1.5.3 and has always worked in the past

Comment: Have you installed Batarang?

Comment: It's disabled, as its been for months, I always found it too slow.  I didn't think you needed it for this.  This issue only started since change computer this week

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've worked out the issue.  In the screenshot below there is a dropdown currently selected as 'top', it was set to JSON Formatter (a plugin I have). So it was trying to run the command in the wrong scope.

[image: Dev Tools]

Ignore the top error (failed to load), that's unrelated.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I'm wondering why it got changed without my consent.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after clicking on an HTML element which is enclosed with an $scope.